# Should I not use variable variables in getters and setters?

Tags: php, variables

Are there any potential pitfalls to using

```
$this->{$name}
```

instead of

```
$this->some_array[$name]
```

in my class getters and setters?

To clarify, I mean WITHIN the __get and __set methods, not while calling them.

**For example:**

```
function __get($name) {
  ...
  return $this->{$name};
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how the two code snippets are related? One appears to be a scalar property while the other is an array property item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A getter/setter will only be invoked if the property is not accessible directly. When dynamically setting properties that are not defined in the class itself, the property will be created with `public` visibility. Which means it's accessible from anywhere, and the getters/setters will not be invoked when accessing it.

To illustrate, the below outputs "setting bar" only once:

```
class Foo {

    public function __set($name, $val) {
        echo "setting $name\n";
        $this->$name = $val;
    }

}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar = 'baz';
$foo->bar = 42;
```

That's probably not something you want. Furthermore, it allows anybody to change any property of your object, which is probably also not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll start noticing a difference if you ever want to cast your objects to arrays, ala (array)$object

Neither way is "best" practice, make a decision based on need, and if that doesnt matter, flip a coin.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the gist of what you're asking.

Using an array makes it easier to grab all the variables that have been set by accessing a single variable, rather than having a bunch of class variables scattered everywhere that you can't fetch easily. I use arrays as lot because I often use the magic methods to access variables related to the object easier (`$obj->property` rather than `$obj->array['property']`).

Using `$this->{$name}` is a bit redundant unless you're running checks inside your __get and __set methods. For example, don't do something like this:

```
function __set($property, $value) {
    $this->{$property} = $value;
}
```

This is essentially what is achieved already by using `$obj->property = 'some value';`...